# Git: restore original file of github shared project that appear modified in my local history

Tags: git, github

Working on Open Source project shared on Github, it might happen to temporally change a file on a forked repository (e.g add a printf for help debugging and remove it when everything works properly). This file is not part of the files that you want to modify, but during debugging you make a commit (i.e add "printf")  and this file is included in the local history. Even if you remove the changes (i.e delete "printf") this file remains in your local history. Then, when you push your local branch online, it appears that you have contributed to this file. 
What's the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the changes are only on your local repository and were not pushed yet. You can `rebase` your local branch.

Then you can either:

- remove the commit that added the `printf`.
- Squash all commits together, so you will only have one bigger commit without detailed history.

For the first option, perform `git rebase -i` and remove the commits that you don't want.

I suggest reading more about rebase in the official docs:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

The basic flow is (assuming you are working on master):

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master -i
... Edit the list of commits according to instructions
... Save and exit
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unnecessary commits while you make pushes to other repos, you can reset your local repo to mirror the upstream(the remote repo), before you make any legitimate commits.

To reset your changes follow these steps.

1. Fetch all changes from from upstream repo.

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   ```
2. To reset your local branch and sync it **upstream** repo, you can run the command.

   ```
   git reset --hard upstream/<branch-name>
   ```

where **`<branch-name>`** is the name of the branch, which you would like to sync.
For example if you would like to reset your *master* branch to mirror the *master* on the remote(upstream) repo.
You can run the following command while you are on *master* branch.

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

To sum it up:

```
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```